# How to validate email or phone fields in form array in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have two fields
**Email** & **Phone**

It's multiple fields. Add new contact with add more button so I have used **FormArray**.

**But point is that only one field is required email or phone** 
So how to validate one field is required in FormArray?

Below is my latest code.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
     contact: this.fb.array([this.addNewContact()]),
});

public addNewContact() {
    return this.fb.group({
        department: [''],
        phone: [''],
        email: [
            '',
            Validators.compose([
                Validators.pattern(/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,15})$/)
            ])
        ],
    },
    this.emailOrPhone());
}

public emailOrPhone() {
    return (form: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
        console.log(form);
        return (!form.value.phone && !form.value.email) ? { isEmailOrMobile: true } : null;
    };
}
```

I have worked on angular 5.

Comment: can you load any of the latest code

Comment: I have updated my question. so check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to use Custom validator.

Create A directive like below  :

```
import {
    FormGroup,
    ValidationErrors,
    ValidatorFn,
    Validators,
  } from '@angular/forms';

  export const atLeastOne = (validator: ValidatorFn, controls:string[] = null) => (
    group: FormGroup,
  ): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if(!controls){
      controls = Object.keys(group.controls)
    }

    const hasAtLeastOne = group && group.controls && controls
      .some(k => !validator(group.controls[k]));

    return hasAtLeastOne ? null : {
      atLeastOne: true,
    };
  };
```

the formBuilder should look like below :

```
return this.fb.group({
  department: [''],
        phone: [''],
        email: [
            '',
            Validators.compose([
                Validators.pattern(/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,15})$/)
            ])
        ],
}, { validator: atLeastOne(Validators.required, ['email','phone']) })
```

Using this directive you can check either of them are valid or not .

This can be reused to any other forms as well. 
Here is a sample working example of the validator : 
[Working demo of atleast one validator](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4rcurm)

You can modify this according to your requirement.

Comment: I have set error message in html " <span *ngIf="form.hasError('atLeastOne')">Email or Phone is required</span> ". but its not working. can you help me?

Comment: you can print all the errors on the field as  `<span class="error" *ngIf=" form.get('email').touched ||form.get('email').dirty" >
      {{ form.controls['email']['errors'] | json }} </span>`

Answer (score 1):

A sort way would be, add both the validation with the change in one of the forms you can disable the other one and vice-versa.

```
public addNewContact() {
return this.fb.group({
    department: [''],
    phone: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    email: [
        '',
        Validators.compose([Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern(/^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,15})$/)
        ])
    ],
},
```

}

then monitor the change on each field and remove the validation accordingly

```
 this.form.get('phone').removeValidator('required');
```

or

```
this.form.get('email').removeValidator('required');
```